# Scroll Activity to top

Tags: android, android-activity

I tried and searched a lot, but did not find an answer for this. I have an activity A, transparent over an Activity B. I am trying to make the activity A scroll up to the top, like the notification bar, so that activity B becomes active. And I should be able to scroll down back A when necessary. Moreover, I am trying to implement this scrolling over an imageview in A, not anywhere on the activity A. can onTouch and onTouchListener help me? Please help me here. I am searching an answer to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can animate Activity A to the top, saving its state, and have it start Activity B and then stop. When the user swipes down in an attempt to get back Activity A, Activity B simply starts A, which starts by animating down from the top. It restores the data it has saved, so to the user it's the same as if it has been active all the time. 
If you need Activity A to continue processing, you an either delegate processing to Activity B, or to a Service, or to a class that is under control of RoboGuice and is kept active because it's injected in both A and B.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to do this is with [`Activity.overridePendingTranistion`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29).  Using this, you will have to start and finish your activity each time for it to animate.  Have you considered using a view that animates down, like a [`SlidingDrawer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)?